# Class method (python) - property setting (active in method) then lost

Tags: python, methods

I'm trying to create a class which holds as property xarray data stored as netcdf

here is the way I started my constructor

```
import xarray as xr

class volume:
''' volume class to contain everything about the seismic dataset
'''
def __init__(cls, name=None, netcdf=None, xarray=None):
    ''' Generic initializer
    '''
    cls.name = name
    cls.netcdf = netcdf
    cls.xarray = xarray

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ class method to load the netcdf file as xarray    
@classmethod
def from_netcdf(cls,netcdf_file):
        ''' Constructor
        '''
        cls.netcdf = netcdf_file

        if netcdf_file is None:
            print('Please define the netcdf file to read')
            return
        else:
            cls.xarray = xr.open_dataarray(netcdf_file)
            cls.name = cls.xarray.attrs['title']
            print('Reading data from netcdf file:{}'.format(netcdf_file))
            print(cls.__repr__(cls))
    
def __repr__(cls):
    ''' Class representation
    '''
    return 'Volume(name={}, netcdf={}, xr={})'.format(cls.name, cls.netcdf, cls.xarray)
```

then run the method on instance the xarray information is there

```
s1 = volume().from_netcdf('2021Feb01.netCDF')
```

> Reading data from netcdf file: 2021Feb01.netCDF
> Volume(name=PSDM OVT unfiltered in time, netcdf= 2021Feb01.netCDF, xr=<xarray.DataArray (IL: 484, XL: 523, TWT: 2750)>
> [696113000 values with dtype=float32]
> ........

So far so good, but I lose the information outside the method as you can see below when I call the **repr** the property information is lost ....

```
s1.__repr__()
```

> 'None'

What am I doing wrong? what's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your `classmethod` is not returning an instance of the class itself.

Here is a very simple example of a classmethod:

```py
class point: 
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def origin(cls): 
        return cls(x=0, y=0)
```

If you want to fix up your code above, you should simply do something like:

```py
@classmethod
def from_netcdf(cls,netcdf_file):
    ''' Constructor'''
    return cls(
        netcdf = netcdf_file, 
        xarray = xr.open_dataarray(netcdf_file)
        name = cls.xarray.attrs['title']
    )
```

Also, in your code above, for any methods that are not classmethods, you should use `self` instead of `cls` to show the distinction between the two

Here's some further reading on the subject https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

great and thanks, it worked with a modification The fix is as follow

''' python
@classmethod
def from_netcdf(cls,netcdf_file):
''' Constructor'''
netcdf = netcdf_file
xarray = xr.open_dataarray(netcdf_file)
name = cls.xarray.attrs['title']
return cls( name, netcdf,xarray) '''

I found that the order name, netcdf, xarray needed to match the same as the one in '''**init**''' declaration